# How can i use PagedListRenderOptions in PagedListPager when using ajax Option?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can i use `PagedListRenderOptions` in `PagedListPager` when using ajax Option.

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page =>
 Url.Action("AllProducts", "Products", new { page }),
 PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "productsContent", OnBegin = "onBeginLoader", OnComplete = "onComplete" }))
```

I wnat somthing like this to modify:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.posts, page =>
 Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions 
{ LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< ابتدا", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "< قبلی", LinkToNextPageFormat = "بعدی>", LinkToLastPageFormat = "آخرین >>" })
```

Comment: please edit your question and include the view code and controller code

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.Net core razor pages

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Trainings,
                   pageNumber => Url.Page("/Training/TrainingList", new {
                       PageNumber = pageNumber,
                       SortBy=Model.SortBy,
                       Search=Model.Search,
                       StartDate=Model.StartDate,
                       Type=Model.Type,
                       TotalCount= Model.Trainings.TotalItemCount
                   }),
                   X.PagedList.Mvc.Common.PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions {
                       OnSuccess="onSuccess",
                       OnFailure ="onFailure",
                       HttpMethod = "GET",
                       UpdateTargetId = "TrainingList",
                       LoadingElementId = "loadingProgress"
                   }))
```

If you dont put UpdateTargetId , you will get -> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # exception

TrainingList is the different page where we are getting data

Return partial view results from page

var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary()) { { "PaginationModel", PaginationModel } };
                myViewData.Model = PaginationModel;

```
            PartialViewResult partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "_PagedTraining",
                ViewData = myViewData,

                ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf8"
            };
```

_PagedTraining -- partial view

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.posts, 
                          page => Url.Action("Index", page }),
                        PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
                                            LinkToFirstPageFormat = "", 
                                            LinkToLastPageFormat = "آخرین >>",
                        new AjaxOptions(){  HttpMethod = "GET", 
                                            UpdateTargetId = "YourTarget",}))
```

Here a [sample](https://github.com/ungleng/SimpleAjaxPagedListAndSearchMVC5) about how to use Ajax PagedList

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/2718699/hadi-hassan but this does not work for me?

Comment: check the sample please, it contains the details how you do it, provide the code of controller and view to have a look on it

Comment: I checked the sample but it does not sense to me!

Comment: provide the code controller and view and what is the error you are facing

Comment: No error in Controller. I just Want to use PagedListRenderOptions in my code

Comment: @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("AllProducts", "Products", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "productsContent", OnBegin = "onBeginLoader", OnComplete = "onComplete" }))

Comment: check this post, https://forums.asp.net/t/1934702.aspx?AJAX+PagedList+Pager, it should help because it is a complete answer

Comment: he is catching the data through ajax call from client side

Answer (score 0):

I'v done it.
To customize do as fllow:

```
Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("AllProducts", "Products",new { page }), 
PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
new PagedListRenderOptions { LinkToFirstPageFormat = " ابتدا", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = " قبلی", LinkToNextPageFormat = "بعدی", LinkToLastPageFormat = "آخرین " }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "productsContent", OnBegin = "onBeginLoader", OnComplete = "onComplete" }))
```